# Método toggle() e position() juntos no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

É possível usar os métodos toggle() e position() na mesma linha de código? Por exemplo:

```
$("#palette-base-category-"+category).toggle("drop", 1000).position({my:"right", at:"right", of:null});
```

att

Answer (score 1):

Possível na maioria das vezes é, só não vejo uma utilidade em fazer isso, nota que o `position()` por definição retorna um objeto que contém as propriedade `top` e `left` e de acordo com a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/position/), ele não aceita nenhum parâmetro, e o [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) simplesmente mostra ou esconde elementos, então não consegui até agora encontrar um uso conjunto em um mesma linha de código, se a pergunta não for só uma curiosidade e você de fato quer fazer algo do tipo, expõem aqui que talvez eu possa te esclarecer mais dúvidas, espero que ajude.

Comment: Tenho um menu, com aquele efeito de exibir e esconder elementos e o que eu queria é fazer com que esses elementos apareçam numa posição específica no lado direito.

Comment: @FernandoMessiasdaSilva como te falei, com o position(), você vai conseguir a posição atual dos elementos, talvez você tenha que utilizar algumas propriedades CSS de posicionamento dentro de uma determinada condição, tipo SE o menu esconder os elementos, da um float:right; neles, algo desse tipo...[Da uma olhada aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174995/dynamically-positioning-elements-using-jquery) é uma resposta de como posicionar itens dinamicamente.